# Java-Stream - Sort and Transform elements using groupingBy()

Tags: java, sorting, set, java-stream

Suppose I have the following domain class:

```
public class OrderRow {
    private Long orderId;
    private String action;
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    
    // getters, constructor, etc.
}
```

I have a following data set of `OrderRow`s :

```
OrderId     Action                  Timestamp
3           Pay money               2015-05-27 12:48:47.000
3           Select Item             2015-05-27 12:44:47.000
1           Generate Payment        2015-05-27 12:55:47.000
2           Pay money               2015-05-27 12:48:47.000
2           Select Item             2015-05-27 12:44:47.000
2           Deliver                 2015-05-27 12:55:47.000
1           Generate Invoice        2015-05-27 12:48:47.000
1           Create PO               2015-05-27 12:44:47.000
3           Deliver                 2015-05-27 12:55:47.000
```

What I want to obtain the following `Map` from the sample data shown above:

```
[3] -> ["Select Item", "Pay money", "Deliver"]
[1] -> ["Create PO", "Generate Invoice", "Generate Payment"]
[2] -> ["Select Item", "Pay money", "Deliver"]
```

By performing below operations :

1. I want to groupBy `orderId`.
2. Sort actions by `timestamp`.
3. Create a `Set` (as there can be duplicates) of `action`s.

I am trying to do this in a single `groupingBy` operation as performing separate sorting, `mapping` operations take a lot of time if data set is huge.

I've tried to do the following:

```
orderRows.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OrderRow::getOrderId, 
        Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),
            Collectors.toCollection(
                () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.timestamp))
    ))));
```

But then I get output as `Map<String, Set<OrderRow>>`
where as I need the result of type `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

Would be really grateful if someone can show me at least a direction to go.

**Note** that is a critical operation and should be done in few milliseconds, hence performance is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

- `LinkedHashSet` - is the only implementation of the `Set` interface, which would to retain the order of the plain `String`s (`action` property), that differs from the alphabetical one.
- *Timsort* has a slightly better performance than sorting via *Red-black tree* (i.e. by storing elments into a `TreeSet`). Since OP has said that *"is a critical operation"*, that worth to take into consideration.

---

You can sort the stream elements by timestamp before applying `collect`. That would guarantee that `action`s in the list would be consumed in the required order.

And to retain the order of these Strings, you can use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (`TreeSet` would not be helpful in this case since you need to keep the order by property which would not be present in the collection).

```
var actionsById = orderRows.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(OrderRow::getTimestamp))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        OrderRow::getOrderId,
        Collectors.mapping(
            OrderRow::getAction,
            Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))
    ));
```

Alternatively, you can sort the sets while grouping (as you were trying to do).

```
var actionsById = orderRows.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        OrderRow::getOrderId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.mapping(
                Function.identity(),
                Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(OrderRow::getTimestamp)))
            ),
            set -> set.stream().map(OrderRow::getAction).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))
        )
    ));
```

Or instead of sorting via *Red-Black Tree* (`TreeSet` *is backed by the an implementation of this data structure*) each set can be sorted via *Timsort* (which is an algorithm used while sorting an array of elements, and `sorted()` operation is invoked in the stream, its elements are being dumped into an array).

Maintaining a *Red-Black Tree* is constful, and theoretically *Timsort* should perform a bit better.

```
var actionsById = orderRows.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        OrderRow::getOrderId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.mapping(
                Function.identity(), Collectors.toList()
            ),
            list -> list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(OrderRow::getTimestamp))
                .map(OrderRow::getAction)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))
        )
    ));
```

To eliminate allocating a new array in memory (which happens when `sorted()` operation is being called) we can sort the lists produced by `mapping()` directly, and then create a stream out of sorted lists in the *finisher* function of `collectingAndThen()`.

That would require writing a multiline lambda, but in this case is justifiable by the performance gain.

```
var actionsById = orderRows.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        OrderRow::getOrderId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.mapping(
                Function.identity(), Collectors.toList()
            ),
            list -> {
                list.sort(Comparator.comparing(OrderRow::getTimestamp));
                return list.stream().map(OrderRow::getAction)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
            }
        )
    ));
```

Comment: I did this exactly, but the time required for doing individual sorting before groupingBy is almost 6 times. This is a critical operation and should be done in few milliseconds. That is why I want to club everything together.

Comment: yes this is solving my problem. Only one thing here is , user of sorted() is adding some performance hit as compared to 
collectingAndThen(
                                    mapping(Function.identity(),  toCollection(
                                            () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.timestamp))
                                    )),
                                    set -> set.stream().map(OrderRow::getEventName)
                                            .collect(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))
                            )))

Comment: @CovetousSlope There's only one reason I can see why *Red-black tree* perform better, namely `sorted()` requires allocating a new array in memory, which has a cost. And it that can be eliminated by sorting an `ArrayList` directly and then creating a stream out of it (I'll update the code in a few minutes). That said, to measure the performance correctly, you need to make sure that the test is isolated and not affected by JVM warm up and other stuff.

Comment: You are right. Seems that memory allocation can be an issue. Also I am running my code multiple times so that I have correct average time.